# Replace only singular word

Tags: regex, replace

I'm trying to do a case sensitive search and replace of the word region with region2 on many php files even for words inside a string, eg: 123region456.

If I start replacing region with region2, the words regions already present become region2s

If I start replacing regions with regions2 and  then replacing region with region2, the word regions2 became region2s2

How to match only a singular word even for words inside a string ?

Thank You

Comment: Sounds like you don't know exactly what your requirement is for your regex.

Comment: Which regex flavour, which language/tool do you use?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to replace `region` and `regions`, you should match both of them:

```
replace /region(s?)/ with "region$12"
```

if you want to match them independently, you can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
replace /region(?!s)/ with "region2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a start, use word-boundarys.

In sed, you use `\<...\>`. i.e.

```
sed 's/\<region\>/region2/g'
```

Comment: The OP said he would want to replace "*even inside a string*"

Comment: yup, that's why I said "as a start"